# Fail to ssh login with public key

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I try to use a public key to connect to a remote server running centos7.

I generated a key by

```
ssh-keygen
```

then copy the key to the server by

```
ssh-copy-id hoa@chip02.phy.ncu.edu.tw
```

the `authorized_keys` is created on the remote machine, but the ssh login still requires the password.

I try to login with triple verbose option

```
ssh -v hoa@chip02.phy.ncu.edu.tw
```

and it give me something like:

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to chip02.phy.ncu.edu.tw [140.115.32.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to chip02.phy.ncu.edu.tw:22 as 'hoa'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ALKc8EF9HMXaCSs/aN4wsfpFN8Bh1W9twUxOTueP5Kk
debug1: Host 'chip02.phy.ncu.edu.tw' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/longhoa/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:S79m96anBkvF16Rjihe80MYbcU1fZlfPxE5686k/vn4 /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/longhoa/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
hoa@chip02.phy.ncu.edu.tw password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password)
```

I searched on google, some mentioned setting the correct permission, I followed the instruction and ended up with
the key on my computer:

```
-rw------- 1 longhoa longhoa 1.7K 23-01-08|14:14:40 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 longhoa longhoa  399 23-01-08|14:14:40 id_rsa.pub
```

the permission on the remote server:

```
drwx------. 2 hoa zh 4.0K 23-01-08|15:10 /home/hoa/.ssh
-rw-------. 1 hoa zh  399 23-01-08|14:23 /home/hoa/.ssh/authorized_keys
dr-xr-xr-x. 29 root root  4096 22-12-27|17:26 /
drwxrwxrwx. 41 root root  4096 22-11-24|18:38 /home
drwx------. 58 hoa  zh   12288 23-01-11|00:47 /home/hoa/
```

There are other answer mention SELinux and debuging from the server but I don't have root access to that server, so I can't not do anything.

So how do I make it work? Thank you very much.

---

**Update 1**

I tried @roaima suggestion.

```
ssh -nvv -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 hoa@chip01.phy.ncu.edu.tw 2>&1 | grep "debug2: host key"
```

which returns:

```
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
```

I also tried id_dsa and id_ed25519, but none seems to work.

---

**Update2**
@roaima and @telcoM pointed out that the remote host was not set up correctly. I will update the status after I talk to the admin.

Comment: Is the SSH server configured to allow key based authentication? Check if both `PubkeyAuthentication` and `AuthorizedKeysFile` are set in `sshd_config`. If you can't, ask the system administrator

Comment: In your examples you seem to have permissions for files on the local server in /home/longhoa and the remote machine in /home/hoa.   The output from the ssh command shows private keys being looked for in /home/longhoa on remote.     It's hard to tell what's happening as the commands you post have myusername.   So as a guess try when logged on as longhoa - ssh -vvv hoa@remote_host_name

Comment: Your key files are `id_rsa`, but your log shows trying `id_dsa`, `id_ecdsa`, and `id_ed25519` only. Try enabling `rsa` in the `sshd` config file.

Comment: @user103944 yes, I try to connect from my laptop (username: longhoa) to the server (username: hoa). I editted the question with the correct information.

Comment: Thanks, @Panki, I'll try to contact the admin. Is there any else I can do without the root permission?

Comment: try to genberate an ed25519 key using `ssh-keygen -t ed25519`

Comment: @Archemar I recently tried id_ed25519 and also id_dsa, but none of them works :(

Comment: Where you are showing permissions on the remote server, please add `ls -ld / /home /home/hoa`

Comment: @roaima I added the permission information for / and /home and /home/hoa

Answer (score 1):

I think it's likely that the server administrators have correctly and sensibly disabled the default `ssh-rsa` host key algorithm. This means that the default use of `ssh-keygen` will produce a key pair that's ignored.

You can check this by running this command on the client:

```
ssh -nvv -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=0 hoa@chip02.phy.ncu.edu.tw 2>&1 | grep 'debug2: host key'
```

It will list the acceptable host key algorithms that are supported by both client and server. You should find that `ssh-rsa` has been disabled on the server for (very good) security reasons and as a result is not listed in the second line output of this command.

As an example, here is the output from my running this command against a local system here. You can see that although `ssh-rsa` is listed in the first line (the client) but it is not listed on the second line (the server). The host key algorithm must be listed on both lines for it to be available:

```
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
```

In such a situation, you need to use a specific variation of `ssh-keygen` that uses a key type present on both client and server. Here is one that will generate an ED25519 key pair instead of the default RSA key pair.

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

References

- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/demystifying-ssh-rsa-in-openssh-deprecation-notice-22feb1b52acd
- `man sshd_config`

Comment: for some reason, when I run the command, it shows that `ssh-rsa` is on both lines. Let me update my question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
drwxrwxrwx. 41 root root  4096 22-11-24|18:38 /home
```

On the remote host, **everyone has write access to `/home`, allowing anyone to e.g. rename or delete anyone else's home directory.** That is not correct, and it will cause `sshd` to distrust any `authorized_keys` files within that sub-tree. As a result, SSH public key authentication **will not work** for any user that has their home directory within `/home` and no custom `authorized_keys` file located elsewhere. This affects all key types, not just RSA.

There should be no need whatsoever for regular users to write into `/home`: if there is some sort of centralized user account management (AD, LDAP, NIS or similar) but each system has independent user home directories, then the admin of the remote host might need to install & configure `pam_mkhomedir.so` to automatically create home directories with correct permissions on first login.

The sysadmin of the remote host should do a `sudo chmod 755 /home` or equivalent **as soon as possible** to set the permissions of `/home` to the standard `drwxr-xr-x`. Having `/home` writeable by anyone will allow users to attack each other with a number of old, well-known tricks. Vandalism by a total deletion of another user's home directory is just the simplest possibility.

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that the admin want to give everyone the permission to create their own `/home/username/` using the `mkdir` command. Is there a good way to set the correct permission while the users are still allow to create their home directories.

Comment: That's indeed a big problem. Any other user can set up any number of evil things to happen when you log in, and make it look like you did those things. The right way would be either to create the home directories by admin action at user account creation time (while also supplying any template login scripts and other configuration from `/etc/skel` automatically) or to install `pam_mkhomedir` which will create a home directory automatically (with the correct permissions and `/etc/skel/` content) if it does not already exist when the user logs in.